# Turning Key, Value pairs from a Dictionary into strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a string template that I need to fill in with the key, value pairs from the dictionary.

For example, if the dictionary was {'a':'1', 'b':'2'} then I need the string template (key is in value) to read as: "a is in 1" and "b is in 2"

And I need to iterate through the dictionary and apply each key, value pair into the string template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Simply iterate the key, value pairs and format your template.

```
mydict = {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}

for key, value in mydict.items():
    print('{} is in {}'.format(key, value))
```

Output:

```
a is in 1
b is in 2
```

If you would like to get a list of formated strings just do:

```
mylist = ['{} is in {}'.format(key, value) for key, value in mydict.items()]
```

`mylist` will be `['a is in 1', 'b is in 2']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function:

```
def fill(d, template):
    s = ""
    for k, v in d.items():
        s += f"{k} {template} {v}\n"
    return s[:-1]

>>> d = {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}
>>> print(fill(d, 'is in'))
a is in 1
b is in 2
```

Note that this will only preserve order in python 3.6+.

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}
template = '{} is in {}'
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print(template.format(key, value))
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You could be fancy and use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap

d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'} 
list(starmap('{} is in {}'.format, d.items()))
# ['a is in 1', 'b is in 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an f-string for python 3.5+:

```py
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}

print('\n'.join(f'{k} is in {v}' for k, v in d.items()))
a is in 1
b is in 2
```

Comment: In this way, all the values should be the ``string``

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi f-strings allow the same flexibility as `str.format`